# load json file in my firefox addon

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox addon, in one of my js files I have an object that I use in my script. 
Now I need this object online as json, so I'm going to add this json file on the server. And every time I run script the first thing it will have to do is include that file.

How can I do this with javascript?
Something similar as PHP include something?

I can't use jQuery

Comment: Have a AJAX call to the url(server file that should provide the object as response) on top of your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im trying to do this:

```
var locations = loadLocations();
function loadLocations() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
            //console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://.../locations.json",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
console.log(locations);
```

but firefox show me error `debugger eval code` on line `xmlhttp.send();`

when i do `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` inside the functions, it shows me everything, but when i return this, dont show anything

Comment: return wouldn't get the data. JS won't wait to execute the next statement till ajax gets the response, just executes the next statement after initiating the ajax call. You can use callback instead. Check this out jsfiddle.net/noboundaries/6LLPh

Comment: exactly, I read more about this. But anyway, i fixed this problem calling all the functions that i need inside this

Answer (score 1):

Have a AJAX call to the url(server file that should provide the object as response) on top of your script.

See here for AJAX call, http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Should the communication happen between domains, ie, if the file that holds JSON object hosted in abc.xom and script file that makes AJAX call hosted in XYZ.com then set Access-Control headers with response that would work with CORS enabled browsers http://enable-cors.org/client.html.  For Non-CORS browser we should go with JSONP object/call.

Comment: but firefox is getting me the error debugger eval code on the line xmlhttp.send(); even the code works, i can see everything on xmlhttp.responseText. but i cant return anything from there

Comment: return wouldn't get the data. JS won't wait to execute the next statement till ajax gets the response, just executes the next statement after initiating the ajax call. You can use callback instead. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/noboundaries/6LLPh/